# Calculate Text formula (NO VBA and NO Evaluate)

Tags: excel, xls

I am using Excel to calculate a string value where Evaluate() works fine **but** I am ***not*** allowed to use evaluate() in the Name Manager and I am ***not*** allowed to use it in VB A because the file gets converted to .xls. Here is the issue.

I have 100 s of a long formula example:

```
($F$10+0)+($F$11+0.125)+($F$10+0.0625)
```

which i need to evaluate the values between the brackets separately. 
I am able to separate the formula to

```
A1 is ($F$10+0)          
A2 is ($F$11+0.125)       
A3 is ($F$10+0.0625)
```

I would like to put an "=" sign in front of this string and calculate the values of A1, A2, and A3. 
However I am not allowed to use function EVALUATE() in the File Manager, it does not work in the cells and I am not allowed to use VB A to code the formula.
is there any replacement for evaluate that I can use? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the dark side of Excel.

**If you cannot use:**

1) VBA

2) Macros

3) Evaluate()

4) File Manager / Define Name

Then there are no simple formulas that can help you (plus you can't make your own).  Microsoft has purposely not addressed this issue for many many years.

So you are left to your own devices to create your own parser in Excel cells.

This can be very difficult if you have varying types of formulas that can change signs, or amount of addressed cells, or any number of other craziness that formulas can take.

However... if you have a minimum number of deviations for how the formula is expressed... you can write something that will do the trick.

This comes with a caveat... the formula must be provided with the same parameters each time.  And what you gave as examples, has the structure defined exactly the same for each formula.

So therefore, using your examples, you can write this code in column A2:

```
=INDIRECT(MID(A1,SEARCH("$",A1),SEARCH("+",A1)-SEARCH("$",A1)),TRUE)+MID(A1,SEARCH("+",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("+",A1)-1)
```

Then you can copy that code over to B2 and C2.

This will give you the correct math as if it was a formula.

**The structural parameters that are needed for this to work are:**

1) The cell address must always start with a dollar sign $

2) The cell address must be immediately followed by a plus sign +

3) Only a single addition is done as the formula

4) The operand after the plus sign must be numeric

5) The formula must end with a Parenthesis )

6) It can't hurt to begin with a Parenthesis either (

And since all of your formulas adhere to this structure... the formula I provided will work.

If you need to change item 3 to also allow for 'subtraction', then you are going to need to add if statements to the formula and it's going to become complicated very quickly.  Impossible? No.  But a huge mess? Yes.

Anyway, this should work with all of your restrictions that you have.  That is... if your formulas don't deviate from the structure that has been provided.  If you have different formula structures, you'd need to let us know about them... or better yet, write your own code.

Hope this helped. :)

Comment: Thanks Abra. I''ll wait for some more feedback but this does the trick and as you said with limitations. I sometimes have 3 sections between the parenthesis or sometimes there is a multiplication inside. I have to toy around with this and see if I can generate helper formulas but it is an excellent start
For me MS is amazing with all their flaws. I am working with an ERP. they use Excel in the background. they are limited-Not MS. I think majority of ERP companies don't deserve the multi-billion dollar industry they have. They just try to fit a square in circle to sell and hook you for life

Comment: Lol... you are probably right about many ERP's.  And "toying" around is the fun part. :)  And yes, breaking it down into 3 sections could be tricky, especially with multiplication in the mix.  PEDMAS is now a concern.  When writing complicated Cell code, I find it easier to break each function into it's own cell and have lots of cells calling previous cells. All on a different sheet so I can document what all the craziness is doing. Then at the end combine them into one hulking formula to paste back on the main page.  "Documentation" being the key word there.